# Flutter Dart Model Class - Combining two classes - One To One - Facing type _InternalLinkedHashMap(String, DYnamic) is not type of second Class

Tags: flutter, dart

This is response from api:

```
{
   "username":"ADuBswdi0LVzJJYkEshGuMsSp393",
   "last_name":"Bond",
   "first_name":"James",
   "email":"jamesbond@gmail.com",
   "userprofile":{
      "phone":"+19999999",
      "bio":"About James",
      "dob":"1970-01-01",
      "role":"Agent"
   }
}
```

I am trying to fit the above result to data model like this.

```
class UserProfileObj {
  String? phoneNumber;
  String? joinedDate;
  String? updatedDate;
  String? dob;
  String? bio;
  String? role;
  UserProfileObj.initial()
      : phoneNumber = '',
        joinedDate = '',
        updatedDate = '',
        dob = '',
        bio = '',
        role = '';
  UserProfileObj({
    required this.phoneNumber,
    required this.joinedDate,
    required this.updatedDate,
    required this.dob,
    required this.bio,
    required this.role,
  });
  UserProfileObj.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    phoneNumber = json['phone'];
    joinedDate = json['joined_date'];
    updatedDate = json['updated_date'];
    dob = json['dob'];
    bio = json['bio'];
    role = json['role'];
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};

    data['phone'] = phoneNumber;
    data['joined_date'] = joinedDate;
    data['updated_date'] = updatedDate;
    data['dob'] = dob;
    data['bio'] = bio;
    data['role'] = role;

    return data;
  }
}

class UserObj {
  String? userName;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? emailAddress;
  UserProfileObj? userProfile;
  UserObj.initial()
      : userName = '',
        emailAddress = '',
        firstName = '',
        lastName = '',
        userProfile = UserProfileObj.initial();
  UserObj(
      {required this.userName,
      required this.firstName,
      required this.lastName,
      required this.emailAddress,
      this.userProfile});

  UserObj.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userName = json['username'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    emailAddress = json['email'];
    userProfile = json['userprofile'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['username'] = userName;
    data['first_name'] = firstName;
    data['last_name'] = lastName;
    data['userprofile'] = userProfile;
    data['email'] = emailAddress;

    return data;
  }
}
```

one of the FormField I am trying to get data like this.

```
...
 FormBuilderTextField(
                            name: 'bio',
                            initialValue: snapshot.data!.userProfile?.bio,
                            decoration:
                                const InputDecoration(labelText: "About You"),
                            minLines: 3,
                            maxLines: 5,
                            onChanged: _onChanged,
                            validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                              FormBuilderValidators.required(),
                            ]),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          ),
...
```

snapshot.data is UserObj as snapshot.data!.emailAddress does show data on the form field but snapshot.data!.userprofile.bio doesn't show the data but error type _InternalLinkedHashMap(String, DYnamic) is not type of userProfileObj.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I didn't try this, but check if replacing `userProfile = json['userprofile'];` with `userProfile = UserProfileObj.fromJson(json['userprofile']);` will help.

Comment: Yes it did the trick. Thank you very much, will you post as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `userProfile = json['userprofile'];` with `userProfile = UserProfileObj.fromJson(json['userprofile']);`